# Prism ViewLocator : How to fix "Your views must implement IView"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I'm starting a WPF application. I use Prism and its `ViewLocator`.

It implies that when I've a View that has to have a `ViewModel` bound to it, I've to indicate on it `mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`and make it implements the `IView` interface, which I did, in the code behind.

In my small test application, every thing works fine, I get my ViewModel, it is set to the DataContext of my View.

The issue is that everyplace I'm using the `mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`, I get this error in the "Error List":

"Your views must implement IView"

From my understanding, the issue is that the xaml editor doesn't seems to check if my code behind class implement this interface.

So how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

In fact Prism 6, which has just been released yet, remove the need of having an `IView`, so you don't have this message anymore :)

Comment: IView is not there in Prism 6 and it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

The XAML Editor gives an error message when you locate your View Model in XAML. You can instead do the job in code behind:

```
public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(this);
}
```

Then no error message is shown.

Comment: Thank you, but we like a lot to be able at the design time, in the XAML to see what usercontrol is AutoWired

Comment: I found this a very neat solution to the damned XAML editor that always produces false errors for a whole host of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to upgrade to Prism 6, here's the solution.

Take the [source code of the ViewModelLocator class](https://github.com/waynebloss/prism-winforms/blob/master/src/PrismLibrary/Prism.Mvvm.Desktop/ViewModelLocator.cs) and in the `AutoWireViewModelChanged` method remove this line:

```
 // throw new Exception("Your views must implement IView");
```

Change the namespace of this class to your namespace:

```
// namespace Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm
namespace MyNamespace
```

And in XAML use this property instead of the one from Prism:

```
<Page 
   xmlns:my="using:MyNamespace"
   my:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```